# What are some easy to use 3D painting programs?

Tags: 3d

I'm looking for an (easy to use) "3D painting" program, a program that lets me load up a UV-mapped mesh, some textures and lets me 'paint' with those different textures.

Exactly like all those terrain painting programs (Unity 3D has one integrated for example) but for a generic mesh, not just a height map.

Cheap is better of course but ease to use is the most important.

Script support is a big plus though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really easy to do on-surface painting with Blender: either 2.49b which has the better documentation, or 2.5 which has the vastly improved interface. I would check out the "Johnny Blender" tutorials on youtube for Blender in general, though I'm not sure if the guy who made them covers this particular topic.

And of course, it's totally free, and supports scripting through python, and there are tons of export scripts and so on out there for different formats eg. FBX.

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial covering [texture painting in Blender 2.5](http://www.blendercookie.com/2011/04/11/texture-painting-in-glsl-shading-mode/)

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Sculptris](http://www.pixologic.com/sculptris/) - free, easy to use, and can be used to create high-quality organic models as well.

Comment: Looks more like a sculpting tool. Can you paint textures as well? Eg. load an image and paint that (not affecting geometry, but the texture).

Comment: @bummzack: Yes, you can. It can do both - sculpting (starting off from a default base or any object you import), and painting. What's more, you can switch between the modes to graft some details onto the object, to use for future normal map generation.

Comment: Nice. Will try this sometime.

Comment: Wow, that looks impressive.

Comment: Seems what I need but does it support scripting?

Comment: @Valmond: It doesn't have any scripting that I know of, and a quick look through the features web page seems to confirm that. It's an artist's tool, basically.

Comment: I just noticed that it's made by pixologic, that also made z-brush. I wonder why the made both programs, instead of both in one.

Comment: @Dan the Man: [Tomas "DrPetter" Pettersson](http://drpetter.se/) was hired by Pixologic after he made Sculptris and it generated quite a following among the 3D artists. He then [decided to host the application on their site](http://drpetter.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=sculptris&action=display&thread=954).

Answer (score 3):

There's [mudbox](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=13565063&siteID=123112). It's [free](http://students.autodesk.com/) if you're a student (non-commercial).